# How to convert some fields of a row into a column emp_id, month, year

Tags: sql-server, excel

Table data:

```
code        salary      TA     DA     month   year 
--------------------------------------------------
01          30000     5000    1000     01    2015
```

Output required:

```
Code         amount   month  year 
------------------------------------
01             30000      01  2015  
01              5000      01  2015
01              1000      01  2015
```

[Please check the data in table and required output in image format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njtod.jpg)

Comment: Please **EXPLAIN** in plain English what you're trying to do - don't just dump two piles of data on us and let us *wonder* what you might want to do .....

Comment: Hi, I have row wise employee data. I want to convert the data like salary, TA , DA in to column wise from single row. As shown in out put emp code, month, year should be maintained same.

Comment: You can see the out put in jpg format. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Cross Apply with Values,
Below code is as per the image

```
 SELECT      Empcode,
                B.Amount,
                Month_attd,
                Year_attd
    FROM        #Your_Table A
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES(Salary),
                        (Phone_all),
                        (Proff_tax)) B (Amount)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, The query is working fine for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (code int, salary int, TA int, DA int, month int, year int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (code, salary, TA, DA, month, year)
VALUES
    (01, 30000, 5000, 1000, 01, 2015)
;

select code,amount,month,year
from @Table1 s
unpivot
(
  amount
  for val in (salary, TA, DA)
) u;
```